How can I add data values while creating/initializing the List<List<String>> directly in Java?
List<List<<String>String>> cars = new ArrayList<>();
cars.add(List.of("1", "Silver", "3000"));
cars.add(List.of("2", "White", "4000"));
cars.add(List.of("3", "Black", "3000"));
cars.add(List.of("4", "White", "3000"));
cars.add(List.of("5", "Blue", "5000"));
cars.add(List.of("6", "Silver", "2000"));

If I need to create and initialize a List<List<<String>String>> like this along with the data directly, How can I avoid multiple list.add(s), multiple List.of (basically multiple steps)? And is it possible if I can create in one line of code?
NOTE : I am not looking for solutions such as list.add(anotherList).

Anything wrong with List<List<String>> cars = List.of(List.of("1", "Silver", "3000"), List.of(...), ...);? That’s how I would write it. I would break over several lines, though.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can’t compile your code. Please post code that can be compiled. Also, how is the question related to foreach and streams? Those tags don’t seem relevant to me.

Is there a good reason you want to work with a list of lists, instead of a list of domain objects as the answer by rzwitserloot suggests?

You may of course initialize a String[][] first since array initializers are quite terse, and then find some elegant way to convert it to a list of lists. Personally I would not bother.

You'd have to write your own method, or List.of(List.of(1, 2), List.of(3, 4)), to make a List<List<Integer>> if you want to stick with the core libraries.
Note that the provided example is problematic. This:

cars.add(List.of("1", "Silver", "3000"));

Is not how it is done; you'd do:
class Car {
  int id;
  PaintColor color;
  int amountCents;
}

and go from there. Make it nice with lombok's @Value or use a record.
Java is highly nominal and explicitly typed. It is designed for you to represent things using named types, not by making all the explicit typing just pointless drivel that gets in the way.  It'll compile, but it'll be hard to maintain, hard to test, frustrating to write, and hard to read.
Done right, this question is no longer relevant. lists-of-lists as  constants doesn't come up a lot if you 'do it right', and in the few places it does, there tends to be so much data you should stick that in a text file of some sort and use a static {} block to read it in.
